# How do i download an entire Alibaba OSS bucket?

Tags: cloud, command-line-interface, storage, alibaba-cloud

It seems, there is no option in the OSS console to download the entire bucket. I also thought to move data from some buckets to a new bucket and then to download the entire bucket using `wget` command by making the new bucket public. Is it safe? Is any easy way available to download the entire bucket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wget` is an http tool. It does not know how to read storage structures from OSS.

The correct tool to use is `ossutil`. Example command to recursively download:

```
ossutil cp -r oss://mybucket mylocaldir
```

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend OSS Browser. It is a midnight commander / total commander style tool.

[OSS Browser on Github](https://github.com/aliyun/oss-browser)

You can have a nice overview of all buckets, download/upload multiple objects/folders at once. I use it every day.

[image: OSS Browser]

Comment: Looks very interesting, but unfortunately I can't read Chinese language... Do you know if they have an English version and documentation?

Comment: Here is the documentation link in English https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/61872.htm. The software itself is in English as well. See screenshot above.

Comment: I looked for the English docs in the Github repo only, didn't think it was an official project from Alibaba Cloud team. Found out that "Aliyun" is the old name for Alibaba Cloud. Just started familiarizing with their cloud services. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

OSS provides more functions than you saw in API.

Check the link below.
https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/44075.htm

And @John Hanley is already right on the point for you question.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in Alibaba Cloud [OSS Bucket Documentation](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/31887.htm)

- Log on to the OSS console.
- In the bucket name list, click the name of the bucket that you created.
- Click the Files tab.
- Click the name of the file that you uploaded, or click Configure to open the Preview page. You can see the following options:

  - Download: used to download a file to your local PC.
  - Open File URL: used to open the file in a browser. Files that cannot be opened directly, such as Excel files, are downloaded directly when the URL is opened.
  - Copy File URL: used to give the URL to anyone who needs to open or download the file.
  - Copy File Path: used to search a file or place watermarks on an image file.

  Note You can also download files by the following methods:

  - Locate the target file, and then select **More > Download**.
  - Select one or more files, and then select **Batch operation > Download.**
- If your bucket ACL is Private, you must set Validity Period when getting a file URL.

Comment: Yep...We can select multiple files and download... But I want to download the entire bucket.